# Decoding from CSV - French and Spanish special characters

Tags: python, csv, utf-8, character-encoding, beautifulsoup

I'm encoding my CSV_table from scrapping process like this :

```
with open("Raw_table.csv", 'w',encoding="utf-8") as outfile:
   csv_writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL,)
```

Usually, when i want to use them i use a csv_parser like this :

```
def parse_csv(content, delimiter = ';'):  
  csv_data = []
  for line in content.split('\n'):
    csv_data.append( [x.strip() for x in line.split( delimiter )] ) # strips spaces also
  return csv_data


list_raw=parse_csv(open('Raw_RC.csv','r',encoding="utf-8").read())
```

It works when i'm scrapping from USA, England website. 
Here i have to deal with French, Spanish and German things it gives me such error when trying to read from the csv with `parse_csv`

```
    csv_writer.writerow([k] + v)
ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 23: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How can i fix this ?

Subsidiary questions :

1. Should I encode the CSV, scrap the site another way (e.g set BeautifoulSoup differently) otherwise when it's german or french ?
2. This encoding problem can be related with all of the `\xa0` i get from scrapping ? I don't think so because i'm able to parse UK,USA cdv whereas there are also full of them.

Every bytes of your time you take to solve this is appreciated ! :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with french/german/spanish character (website written in that language), don't use : `encoding='utf-8'` but `encoding='ISO-8859-1'` instead.

So writing :

```
with open("Raw_table.csv", 'w',encoding="ISO-8859-1") as outfile:
   csv_writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL,)
```

And reading :

```
list_raw=parse_csv(open('Raw_RC.csv','r',encoding="ISO-8859-1").read())
```

The \xa0 problem is not related. Indeed, it occurs only in UTF-8. So my specific french/german typography wasn't related. 
To go further on this matter (which wasn't the core of the question) please see the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20) suggested by tripleee.